# "over" in "California's paralysis over the death penalty system"

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions, usage

A question about the usage of "over" [here](http://www.times-standard.com/localnews/ci_26531209/calif-death-penalty-support-falls-12-percent-3):

> A Los Angeles federal judge added to ***California's paralysis over*** the death penalty system this summer, declaring the law unconstitutional because of delays that leave condemned murderers awaiting execution for 25 to 30 years.

A paralysis is not really a "*discussion*", "*argument*", or "*fight*", words that are traditionally used with "*over*".

Could it be that the writer is using some unusual meaning of "paralysis"?

Answer (score 1):

For "over", I would use Collins [over](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/over) sense 18:

> 18) about; concerning   ⇒ "a quarrel over politics"

And for "paralysis", I would use Collins [paralysis](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/paralysis) sense 2:

> 2) any condition of helpless inactivity or of inability to act

Basically it is saying California has an *inability* to take action *concerning* the death penalty system, due to legal delays. (Yes it is really true.)